# regex stored in json not parsing

Tags: python, json, regex

I have a JSON dict which contains two regular expressions for how I want a string formatted.

```
{
    "codes": {
        "ed_code": "r'(\\D{3})(\\d{3})(\\d*)'",
        "ed_pattern": "'\\1_\\2'"
    }
}
```

In Python, I want to format a string based on the rules inside the  config.json file.

```
import json

_CONFIG_FILE = "config.json"
_CONFIG = json.load(open(_CONFIG))

a="XYZ290290781"
code = _CONFIG['codes']['ed_code']
pattern= _CONFIG['codes']['ed_pattern']
ed_format = re.sub(code,pattern,a)
```

Printing ed_format returns exactly what x is. It should return `XYZ_290`. I'm thinking code and pattern aren't being passed from the JSON file properly. Am I right in thinking this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove extra symbols (**'** and **r**) from json file. To do that can simply:

```
a="XYZ290290781"
code = _CONFIG['codes']['ed_code'].strip("r").strip("'")
pattern= _CONFIG['codes']['ed_pattern'].strip("'")
ed_format = re.sub(code,pattern,a)
```

Comment: Yep! That solves it!! Is it worth me removing r' in the json dict in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to a mix-up with how the strings are encoded in the JSON, you'll notice they are in two sets of quotes. So if you have control of the JSON change it there, if not you can do the following to recover the original python representations

```
import ast
code = ast.literal_eval(_CONFIG['codes']['ed_code'])
pattern= ast.literal_eval(_CONFIG['codes']['ed_pattern'])
```